# How can Programmatically adding multiple points to the map using esri in flex map

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dictionary, flex4.5, esri

I wanna add Multiple Marker to esri map by using flex 4.6 on flash builder platform

> ` 
>               private function addSomeMarkers(x:Number,y:Number):void
>               {

```
            // This is just to show how to add markers
            // using ActionScript code as opposed to MXML tags.
            //(lat, lon, new SpatialReference(102697));
            // outSR:SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
            //GCS_WGS_1984

            var myGraphicMarker:Graphic = new Graphic(new MapPoint(y,x, new SpatialReference(102100)),
                new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND, 14, 0x009933));

            myGraphicMarker.toolTip = "Marker added with ActionScript";
            myGraphicsLayer.add(myGraphicMarker);

            myGraphicMarker=null;
        }`
```

These is my current function recives an (x,y) from dataBase but when i run program it just add only one the first recived x,y .

I checked my my code and im sure the function recives multiple point x,y....

Please help me and thank you>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same type of program and its working fine for me. May be you can try with some hard-coded values for Map points first. As I can see you are interchanging the positions of "y" and "X" in the map point.

var myGraphicMarker:Graphic = new Graphic(new MapPoint(**y**,**x**, new SpatialReference(102100)),
                new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND, 14, 0x009933));